# Antd item.list removes always removes first last element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, listview, antd

Hi there I made  simple antd list where user can add, remove edit list.
But the problem is that when i add, edit list verything works as it should.
But when i remove item from a list, antd always remove last item from a list.
Although i can remove any item.

```
  const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([])
    <List
      dataSource={employeeList}
      renderItem={(item, index) => (
       <List.Item id='listItem' >
         <Input 
          id='listItem-input'
          defaultValue={item.name} 
          onChange={(i) => {
            employeeList[index].name = i.target.value
            setEmployeeList(answerList)   
          }}
        />
        <span className='removeItem' 
          onClick={() => {
            let newList = setEmployeeList
            newList[index] = undefined
            setEmployeeList(newList.filter(e => e))
           }}
         >
           <CloseOutlined/>
         </span>
       </List.Item>
     )}
  />
```

I checked in console items in state gets removed, although it still stays in item.list

Comment: what is `index` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't add it.
It is a index of element renderItem={(item, index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to use a keys.
List.Item wasn't registering changes without keys and was just deleting last item, on any change.

```
<List.Item id='listItem' key={item.answer} >
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recomend deleting items with [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

so rather then this 3 lines in onClick (in remove) just

```
employeeList.splice(index,1)
```

##### Edit:

With your approach you probably want:

```
 let newList = employeeList
 newList[index] = undefined
```

Comment: I tried to use splice also but it doesn't work correctly for me.
That is why i ended up using this aproach.
It works, altough it looks like there ase some render issue, and input field holds old value

Comment: @KarinaShulan look my edit, you setting newList as function setEmployeeList